# Simplify rational function with removable singularity

Tags: simplifying-expressions

In this example I consider a rational function f
( `{n \[Element] Integers, n > 0, v \[Element] Reals, 0 < v < 1}` )

```
f =(5 (-1)^n + 2 v - 10 (-1)^n v - v^2 +5 (-1)^n v^2 + (-1 + 2 v)^(2 + n) (-5 + 4 v) + 
2 n (-1 + v) ((-1)^n (-1 + v) + (-1 + 2 v)^(2 + n)))/(4 (1 + n) (2 + n) (3 + n) (-1 + v)^2 v)
```

, which seems to have singularities at v=0 and v=1 (see denominator).

Limit shows

```
Limit[Numerator[f]/v, v -> 0] (*2 (1 + 7 (-1)^n + 8 (-1)^n n + 2 (-1)^n n^2)*)
Limit[Numerator[f]/(1 - v)^2, v -> 1](*11 + 5 (-1)^n + 2 (5 + (-1)^n) n + 2 n^2*)
```

that the singularities are removable!

How can I "analytically" remove the singularities in f.
Application of Simplify, Apart , Factor doesn't succeed!

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `Cancel`?

Comment: Thanks for your hint, Cancel[] doesn't change f.

Comment: Doing `Apart[f, v]` shows that term singular in `v==0` is proportional to `((-1)^n - (-1 + 2 v)^n)/v`. If by "removing singularities" you mean getting rid of all negative powers of `v`, then I think that, with symbolic `n`, best result you can get is an `Inactive` `Sum` expression coming from binomial theorem: `Inactive[Sum][(-1)^(k + n) 2^(k + 1) v^k Binomial[n, k + 1], {k, 0, 
  n - 1}]`. Is something like that the expected result? Note that if you activate it *Mathematica* will sum it up back to expression with `(...)/v`.

Comment: @jkuczm: Thanks, which is your  MMA ? My MMA 11.0.1 doesn't show the proportionality you mention. I will try the `Inactive Sum`

Comment: In all versions I have, including 11.0.1, I get: `Apart[f, v] (* (2 (-1 + 2 v)^n)/((1 + n) (3 + n)) + ((5 + 2 n) ((-1)^n - (-1 + 2 v)^n))/(4 (6 + 11 n + 6 n^2 + n^3) v) - (-1 + (-1 + 2 v)^n)/(4 (1 + n) (2 + n) (3 + n) (-1 + v)^2) + (-1 + (-1 + 2 v)^n + 2 n (-1 + 2 v)^n)/(4 (1 + n) (2 + n) (3 + n) (-1 + v)) *)`. Second term: `((5 + 2 n) ((-1)^n - (-1 + 2 v)^n))/(4 (6 + 11 n + 6 n^2 + n^3) v)` is the only one with negative power of `v`, it's the one I was referring to.

Comment: @jkuczm Now I got it, thanks.